# "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" when trying to build OpenCV on Jetson Xavier NX

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, jetson-xavier

I am facing an issue while building OpenCV on my Jetson Xavier NX. I encountered the error : "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" and I can't figure out what the origin of this error is.

I was trying to build OpenCV with CUDA support, by executing the script on https://github.com/mdegans/nano_build_opencv/tree/master.

It says that some output check failed. The error logs include the following :

```
Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'argument .* is not valid'
    Output line: 'cc1: warning: ‘-Werror=’ argument ‘-Werror=non-virtual-dtor’ is not valid for C'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type  -Werror=non-virtual-dtor'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_fc99c/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type  -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/src.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
cc1: warning: ‘-Werror=’ argument ‘-Werror=non-virtual-dtor’ is not valid for C
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
Linking C executable cmTC_fc99c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc99c.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_fc99c 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'command[- ]line option .* is valid for .* but not for C\+\+'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations  -Wmissing-prototypes'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_02d25/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations  -Wmissing-prototypes -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wmissing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
Linking CXX executable cmTC_02d25
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_02d25.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_02d25 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'command[- ]line option .* is valid for .* but not for C'
    Output line: 'cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized  -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_e05e1/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized  -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/src.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
Linking C executable cmTC_e05e1
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_e05e1.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_e05e1 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor  -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_18051/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor  -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args’
Linking CXX executable cmTC_18051
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_18051.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_18051 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized  -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_9ec1c/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized  -Wno-unnamed-type-template-args -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/src.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unnamed-type-template-args’
Linking C executable cmTC_9ec1c
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_9ec1c.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_9ec1c 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'command[- ]line option .* is valid for .* but not for C'
    Output line: 'cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fvisibility-inlines-hidden’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_c4ec9/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/src.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
cc1: warning: command line option ‘-fvisibility-inlines-hidden’ is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
Linking C executable cmTC_c4ec9
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc   -O3 -DNDEBUG    CMakeFiles/cmTC_c4ec9.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_c4ec9 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-implicit-const-int-float-conversion’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' -Wno-implicit-const-int-float-conversion'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_fc98e/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/src.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -Wno-implicit-const-int-float-conversion -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/src.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-implicit-const-int-float-conversion’
Linking C executable cmTC_fc98e
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  CMakeFiles/cmTC_fc98e.dir/src.c.o  -o cmTC_fc98e 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Determining if the _aligned_malloc exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_3eb8d/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: error: ‘_aligned_malloc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    8 |   return ((int*)(&_aligned_malloc))[argc];
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:8:19: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:4:14: warning: parameter ‘argc’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-parameter]
    4 | int main(int argc, char** argv)
      |          ~~~~^~~~
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_3eb8d.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_3eb8d/fast] Error 2


File /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckSymbolExists.c:
/* */
#include <malloc.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  (void)argv;
#ifndef _aligned_malloc
  return ((int*)(&_aligned_malloc))[argc];
#else
  (void)argc;
  return 0;
#endif
}
Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_bc2f5/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-undef -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-switch -Wno-parentheses -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-extra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-deprecated -Wno-suggest-override  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override’
Linking CXX executable cmTC_bc2f5
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-undef -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-switch -Wno-parentheses -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-extra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-deprecated -Wno-suggest-override  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  CMakeFiles/cmTC_bc2f5.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_bc2f5 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'command[- ]line option .* is valid for .* but not for C\+\+'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-missing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -Wno-missing-prototypes'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_6eb29/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-undef -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-switch -Wno-parentheses -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-extra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-deprecated -Wno-suggest-override -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-tautological-compare  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -Wno-missing-prototypes -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wno-missing-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
Linking CXX executable cmTC_6eb29
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wsign-promo -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-undef -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-switch -Wno-parentheses -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-extra -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-deprecated -Wno-suggest-override -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-tautological-compare  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  CMakeFiles/cmTC_6eb29.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_6eb29 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

===== END =====

Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-enum-compare-switch’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -Wno-enum-compare-switch'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_078a6/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-sign-promo -Wno-undef -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-extra -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-invalid-offsetof  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -Wno-enum-compare-switch -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-enum-compare-switch’
Linking CXX executable cmTC_078a6
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-deprecated -Wno-missing-declarations -Wno-shadow -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-sign-promo -Wno-undef -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-extra -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-const-variable -Wno-invalid-offsetof  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  CMakeFiles/cmTC_078a6.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_078a6 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====

Determining if the include file sys/videoio.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_f7751/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o
/usr/bin/cc   -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE   -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o   -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFile.c:1:10: fatal error: sys/videoio.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <sys/videoio.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/build.make:66: CMakeFiles/cmTC_f7751.dir/CheckIncludeFile.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_f7751/fast] Error 2



Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'unrecognized .*option'
    Output line: 'cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unused-private-field’'
Compilation failed:
    source file: '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx'
    check option: ' -Wno-unused-private-field'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/make cmTC_a8338/fast && /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/src.cxx.o
/usr/bin/c++    -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-overloaded-virtual  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG -fPIE    -Wno-unused-private-field -std=c++11 -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/src.cxx.o -c /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx
/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.cxx:1: warning: ignoring #pragma   [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    1 | #pragma
      | 
cc1plus: warning: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-unused-private-field’
Linking CXX executable cmTC_a8338
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections    -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -Wno-unused-function -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-overloaded-virtual  -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG    -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed  CMakeFiles/cmTC_a8338.dir/src.cxx.o  -o cmTC_a8338 
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_opencv/opencv/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'


===== END =====
```

Note that I already have CUDA 11.4, cuDNN 8.6 and OpenCV 4.5.4 on the system.

Comment: The line "Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!" just means that the error occurred and you need to look for corresponding error message somewhere **above this line** in the **output**. You will NOT find that error message in the logs (`CMakeErrorLog.txt` or others).